# Running Pig command using JAVA and UNIX

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run a UNIX command through JAVA. My shell command call a pig script.When i do this excersize in unix terminal it works fine, but through java I didn't get any output.

**PFB the code JAVA:**

```
public String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        System.out.println("process started");
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        //p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("before reader");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        //String line = "";         
        System.out.println("After reader   ");
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            System.out.println("inside while loop *******************************");
            output.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println("while loop endedr");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("inside exception");
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

pig_command : 
time pig -param indir="/home/********/INDIR/archived/Bookings/20160620*/part*" -param outdir="/home/*********/OUTDIR/HOURLYBOOKING/20160620/05" -stop_on_failure -x mapreduce /home/directory/pig/pigscript.pig

How i am running java program :
java -cp /home/directory/java_jar.jar com.Example.Tester pig_command

Problem: though the output is getting generated successfully in HDFS the code in the above while loop prints nothing(which should print the job logs).

Answer (score 0):

each call to `readline()` goes to next line in stream. `while` loop in your code is omitting two lines in each `readline()` call (`System.out.println` and `output.append...`) so if output of your pig script is only one or two lines then nothing will be printed on console or appended on StringBuffer (`output`) from `while` loop.

To fix this... your implementation of

```
        //String line = "";         
        System.out.println("After reader   ");
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            System.out.println("inside while loop *******************************");
            output.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
```

should be:

```
        String line = null;         
        System.out.println("After reader   ");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println("inside while loop *******************************");
            output.append(line + "\n");
            System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but This has been already tested, the result is same the code within the while loop is not executed.